Phone audio input and output across devices
Is there a way to have my audio from my headphones play on my Mac in real time?
In my job I have several meetings a day via phone and use a dictation program to record the details. The problem is I have to use my phone on speaker and sit by my computer in order to have the dictation work as the audio is recorded through the computer. I would like to use my headphones connected to my phone so the audio is clear,I can also move around and ideally still somehow have the audio play on my Mac so the dictation software ‘hears’ it and records it.
Is this possible? Is there a way to set up my headphones or computer or phone so the phone call audio in and out of my headphones is still ‘heard’ by my computer audio? I have a Mac air, iPhone, and jabra headset.
Thanks
